# Qt application build for ios using cmake and xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, qt, cmake

I have a Qt application which I can build and run with 2 differents ways, the application works properly on my Mac.

I can run from QtCreator using qbs files.

I can run from Xcode using a .xcodeproject generated by cmake.

Now I want to run my application on an Ipad.
I try from QtCreator but the signing is not working properly (bundle id)

I think i need to use Xcode for the Info.plist generation and let him do the work for selecting the appropriate compiller but i don't know how to add a new "target device".

I open my XcodeProject but my Ipad is not showing on the device pannel next to the run Button. 
When I go on the settings i need to tell him where to find the info.plist but when I hit the "find plist file" i got none. Should I create it in my application folder or use some cmake method ?

[image]

Last things my project is using different libraries, i compile them for ios using the appropriate CC and CXX flags.

Where should I specify the location folder for thoose libraries.

inside the CMakeList with something like this or create a new CMakeList file just for the ios build ?

```
if(WIN32)
elseif(APPLE) #ios flags ???
endif()
```

Comment: I don't think there's a standard way to detect iOS in CMake. You'll probably have to set a custom variable like "IS_IOS_BUILD" that you only pass to CMake when doing an iOS build.

Comment: In a future version of Qbs, we'll have direct integration with Xcode so you'll be able to generate Xcode projects directly from .qbs files without needing CMake at all.

Comment: @Jake Petroules Thank you, do you have an idea on when it will be available and if it will handle Info.plist file. I saw the generator Api and it looks really promising, should we are suppose to run the "qbs generate -g xcode??"  in the same folder that the qbs file ?

Comment: Yes to the command like syntax. Info.plist files will of course be handled and have all the same flexible capabilities as you do in qbs native. I'm not sure when I'll have time to finish it, but I'm hoping for the 1.10 release or so.